# Open file in new tab or split if current file has changes in fzf.vim

Tags: vimscript, neovim, plugin-fzf, fzf

I have been using `:Files` to get a list of files using fzf.vim. Although whenever I hit enter to open a new file and the current file has not been saved I get an error message saying

```
No write since last change
```

In order to open a new file now I either need to save the file and search the new file again or I need to search the new file and open it in a split using `ctrl+h` or `ctrl+v`. Any way I can have the file open in a split or a new tab on hitting `Enter` if the current file has not been saved?

Comment: Does adding `set hidden` to your vimrc solve the problem?

Comment: Oh wasn't aware of this. This does help to a certain extent. But I would also like to know which and how many files have unsaved changes. Additionally does hitting :w save all the unsaved files or only the one which is currently open

Comment: To know how many unsaved buffers you have you can use `:ls` the buffers with a `+` next to their name are unsaved (see [`:h :ls`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Als)). And `:w` only works on the current buffer, if you want to save them all at one you could use [`:h :bufdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo) with something like `:bufdo w`